# Using NSPredicate to search through array of objects

Tags: objective-c, nspredicate

I have an array of instances of a class called `Contact`, which has, among others, the following properties:

```
NSArray *mailAddressList // Array of NSString
NSArray *websiteList // Array of NSString
NSArray *tags // Array of instances of Tag class
```

The class tag has the following properties:

```
NSString *name;
UIColor *color;
```

I want to use NSPredicate to search a string in any property of each `Contact`. This is the code I have:

```
if([scope isEqualToString:SCOPE_MAIL] || [scope isEqualToString:SCOPE_WEBSITE])
{
    // Search through an array
    predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY SELF.%@ contains[c] %@", scope, textSearch];
}
else if([scope isEqualToString:SCOPE_TAG])
{
    // Search another object's property
    predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF.%@.name contains[c] %@", scope, textSearch];
}
else
{
    // The rest of the properties are instances of NSString
    predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF.%@ contains[c] %@", scope, textSearch];
}
```

Everything works fine except for `SCOPE_TAG`, it doesn't return any values. I don't think I'm using the predicate correctly.

**NOTE:** I'm new with NSPredicate so I would like to hear some insights if what I'm doing is not ok

Comment: Not 100% sure whether this is what's responsible for your problem, but you should be using the `%K` format specifier for keypaths instead of `%@`. So for example the format string for `SCOPE_TAG` would be `SELF.%K.name contains[c] %@"`.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I changed it to `%K` but the behaviour didn't change

Comment: Don't you miss the `ANY` in your second predicate statement? I think you want to check if any of the tag names in your array contains the text...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First of all, if you substitute a keypath you should use `%K` as arg.

Further, I think you are missing the `ANY` argument in your second query. I think you want a result if any of the tag names contains your `textSearch`.

To get a better understanding of how predicates work, have a look at the [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pSyntax.html)

I did a quick test and it is still working fine:

```
NSMutableArray *arrayContacts = [NSMutableArray array];

{
    AMContact *contact = [[AMContact alloc] init];
    NSMutableArray *arrayTags = [NSMutableArray array];
    {
        AMTags *tag = [[AMTags alloc] init];
        tag.name = @"Test";
        [arrayTags addObject:tag];
    }

    {
        AMTags *tag = [[AMTags alloc] init];
        tag.name = @"Te2st2";
        [arrayTags addObject:tag];
    }

    {
        AMTags *tag = [[AMTags alloc] init];
        tag.name = @"No";
        [arrayTags addObject:tag];
    }
    contact.tags = [arrayTags copy];
    [arrayContacts addObject:contact];
}

{
    AMContact *contact = [[AMContact alloc] init];
    NSMutableArray *arrayTags = [NSMutableArray array];
    {
        AMTags *tag = [[AMTags alloc] init];
        tag.name = @"Test";
        [arrayTags addObject:tag];
    }
    contact.tags = [arrayTags copy];
    [arrayContacts addObject:contact];
}
NSPredicate *pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY SELF.%K.name contains[c] %@", @"tags", @"Test"];

NSArray *result = [arrayContacts filteredArrayUsingPredicate:pred];

NSLog(@"%@", result);
```

Comment: Thank you! It works perfectly now. I must've made a mistake before, because I tried using `ANY` and I got and exception saying that the operator cannot be used because it's not a collection. This made me think that `ANY` was meant to be used only with arrays, sets, etc.